# Add two textboxes values with 0.5 or 0.75

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add textboxes and the answer to another textbox and it works fine until i use 0.5 or 0.75?

`````
        {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox5.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox6.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
                    textBox10.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text)+ Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text)).ToString();

        }````
`````

Comment: Integers aren't decimals.

Comment: You are using Int32, since 0.5 and 0.75 are not integers, they will not be parsed. Try using `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: How about using `double.TryParse` instead and also handle the situation when the input in the textbox cannot be parsed as a double either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because youre using Convert.ToInt32() try using Convert.ToDecimal()